# Laravel collection AND WHERE clause

Tags: laravel, collections

I'm a bit confused regarding the AND WHERE clause whith collections.
The following query gets all the users owning a car licence OR a motorbike licence:

```
User::whereHas('licences', function($query) {
    $query->whereIn('type', ['car', 'motorbike']);
})->get();
```

Now how to get all the users owning a car licence AND a motorbike licence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try duplication your whereHas:

```
$wantedLicences= ['car', 'motorbike'];
$query=User::query();

foreach($wantedLicences as $wantedLicence)
{
    $query=$query->whereHas('licences', function($query)use($wantedLicence) {
        $query->where('type', $wantedLicence);
    })
}
```

Comment: It seems to work but it gets tedious if I have 3, 4 or more licences. 
Isn't there a simpler way to do that ?

Comment: you can make for each for multiple wanted Licenses

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a User can't have more than one type of a license then you would adjust the `whereHas` to check that the count of related records equals 2:

```
User::whereHas('licenses', function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('type', ['car', 'motorbike']);
}, '=', 2)->get();
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score -1):

The query should be like this for getting users owning a car and a motorcycle

```
User::whereHas('licences', function($query) {
       $query->where('type','car')->where('type','motorbike');
})->get();
```